# Why does an upvote to your question earn you 10 rep but a downvote only takes 2?

Tags: support, reputation, voting

Whenever someone's question gets upvoted, they earn 10 reputation. But when their question gets DOWNVOTED, they only lose 2. Why is this imbalance in place? For example, if one of my questions gets downvoted then re-upvoted, the question score remains the same, but I still earn e8 reputation! How come?

Comment: This https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7322/should-the-weight-of-downvotes-be-increased/42763#42763 is probably a good place to start in order to understand StackExchange's reasoning.

Comment: There aresome related discussions on this meta, too. For example: 
[Point difference between upvotes and downvotes](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9834), 
[Net gain for a poor question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/16769), 
[Why reputation is not changed w.r.t Net votes?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/20020) (Probably you can find a few more.)